# Multiples URI on security integration

Tags: oauth-2.0, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone tell me if is possible to add multiple URI on the security integration on snowflake?
Example :

```
"CREATE OR REPLACE  SECURITY INTEGRATION [IF NOT EXISTS]
  <name>
  TYPE = OAUTH
  OAUTH_CLIENT = CUSTOM
  OAUTH_CLIENT_TYPE = 'CONFIDENTIAL' | 'PUBLIC'
  OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = '<uri1>,<uri2>'"
```

Thank you all.
Daniela

Answer (score 0):

No,it is not possible to have multiple redirect URI for OAuth integration with Snowflake.

Comment: can we make this redirect_uri accept wild cards, like *.abc.com ?